# Ubuntu Server DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system

I need to configure DNS server for my private cloud which is based only on LAN, do i need internet providers dns for forwarder?

forwarders {
      # Replace the address below with the address of your provider's DNS server
      123.123.123.123;
};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question...

You don't need to use forwarders, but it can speed things up (your ISP probably caches lookups for thousands of clients). It will however work without them.

If you mean that your private cloud is 100% offline (should not communicate with the internet) then there is no point in having them.

EDIT: Do -> Don't (sorry about that)

Comment: Yes, its offline i just needed to make sure if its okay to leave it blank so no errors come up thnx.

Comment: Most DNS resolvers have no forwarders. It is completely optional.